# date and Time difference with color difference

Tags: php, css, datetime, php-5.6

Here i am doing task module, now i want  to track the time line, here we have two date

1. Task Due Date (2017-12-28 09:00 PM)
2. Task Completed On (2017-12-28 09:39 AM)

Using this two dates i want to track their time line,suppose before due date i completed my task means i want to show green color and how many days and how many hours i completed his i want to display, same suppose he is delayed  his timeline means i want to show red color and how many days and how many hours i completed his i want to display

> i tried but it is not working properly

```
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
$due_on = '2017-12-28 09:00 PM';
$start_ex = explode(" ",  $due_on);
$start = $start_ex[0].' '.$start_ex[1];
$completedON ='2017-12-28 09:39 AM';
$datetime1 = date_create($start);
$datetime2 = date_create($completedON);
$interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);
echo $time_diff= $interval->format('%R%a days %h hours');
```

> Updated Code

```
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
$compltedOn ='2017-12-28 09:39 PM';//2016-04-17 10:00 AM
$dueDate ='2017-12-28 09:00 PM';//2016-04-17 07:51:30 PM
$datetime1 = date_create($compltedOn);
$datetime2 = date_create($dueDate);
$interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);
echo $time_diff= $interval->format('%R%a days %h hours %i minuts');//-0 days 0 hours 39 minuts 0 seconds
```

Comment: There is a problem with your data - you complete a task '2017-12-28 09:39 AM' before it is started '2017-12-28 09:00 PM'

Comment: '2017-12-28 09:00 PM' this due date, but i completed the task before,so time difference should come 0 days 11 hours

Comment: @ jeff , are getting my question bro ?

Answer (score 0):

Two problems:

1. you are stripping off the PM indicator from the start time so the date_create will treat it as a morning date then compare it with second date - returning difference in minutes.
2. you are using `echo $time_diff= $interval->format('%R%a days %h hours');`
   so chnage this to `$time_diff= $interval->format('%R%a days %h hours'); 
   echo $time_diff;`

Amended code:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
$compltedOn ='2017-12-28 09:39 PM';//2016-04-17 10:00 AM
$dueDate    ='2017-12-28 09:00 PM';//2016-04-17 07:51:30 PM
$datetime1 = date_create($compltedOn);
$datetime2 = date_create($dueDate);
$interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);
$cls = ($interval->invert == 1 ) ? "red" : "green";
$time_diff= "<span class='{$cls}'>".$interval->format('%R%a days %h hours %i minuts')."<span>";
echo $time_diff;
```

Comment: Please see my updated code it working properly i want to do differentiate the color + means green - means red can you please update my answer

Comment: are you there ?